# ActionScript 2 Creating a boolean to check if an answer has been given

Tags: flash, actionscript, boolean, actionscript-2, flashdevelop

So I am currently creating a game in FlashDevelop ActionScript 2, in the game when the player comes into contact with the washing machine the player goes to another screen and answers a question. Once they have answered the question they are taken back to the game to continue, they must then answer all required questions in order to complete the game. However when the player answers a question and are taken back to the game the software thinks that you still haven't answered the question and makes you take it again
Here is the code that I am using which is relative to my problem:

```
static var level:Platform;

//This calls the movieclip I made
static function main(mc:MovieClip):Void
{

    level = new Platform();

}

public function Platform() 
{
    //Creating the variable for the movement details
    var keyListener:Object = new Object();
    var redraw:Object = new Object();

    //Variables to hold the score
    var score:Number = 0;
    var timerstore:Number = 0;

    //Booleans to check if the user has answered the questions
    var washerquestion:Boolean = false;
    var tvquestion:Boolean = false;
    var windowquestion:Boolean = false;
    var lampquestion:Boolean = false;



    redraw = function():Void
    {
        if (_root.player.hitTest(_root.washer))
        {
            if washerquestion = false;
            {
                washerquestion = true;
                _root.gotoAndStop(5);
            }
            if washerquestion = true;
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }


        if (_root.player.hitTest(_root.tv))
        {
            _root.gotoAndStop(6);
            tvquestion = true;
        }

        if (_root.player.hitTest(_root.window))
        {
            _root.gotoAndStop(7);
            windowquestion = true;
        }

        if (_root.player.hitTest(_root.lamp))
        {
            //Removes the players character
            _root.player.unloadMovie();
            //This takes the player to the end screen
            _root.gotoAndStop(4);
            lampquestion = true;
        }

        _root.Finalscoretext.text = score;

    };


    //The redraw function is instigated by the interval timer
    timerstore = setInterval(redraw, 1);
}
```

}

I used Vectorian Giotto to create the movieclips

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the boolean and then execute your function

```
 if(washerquestion){            // if washer == true or you can use else
       your_function();
 }

 if(!washerquestion){      // if washer == false or you can use else
       your_function();
 }
```